# not found The requested resource / was not found on this server

Tags: php, laravel

I want to run a laravel project on local server but I have only the backup from server so I made some changes but now my php artisan is working but when coming to routes  it shows that:

> Not found theb requested resource/was not found on this server

Comment: check your .htaccess file.

Comment: try runinng: composer install in console